# How to find a 4x4 invertible Matrix and a 4x4 real diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am taking a Linear Algebra course and I came across this problem.

> Find a 4 × 4 invertible real matrix P and a 4 × 4 real diagonal matrix Λ such that:
>
> $P^{−1}AP = Λ$.
>
> A note is given that $P^{-1}$ does not need to be calculated.

I am having difficulty with it, I have come across the form $PAP^{−1} = Λ$ before but never $P^{−1}AP= Λ$. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: I missed part of the question that provides context. Full question below.

> In following the following problem **u,v,w** will be the following vectors:
>   $$u = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ 0\\3 \end{pmatrix}, v = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\-1\\1 \end{pmatrix}, q = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\\ 1\\2 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> If a 3×3 matrix M is such that Mu=−5u, Mv=0 and Mw=3w,
>
> Find a 4 × 4 invertible real matrix P and a 4 × 4 real diagonal matrix Λ such that:
>
> P^{−1}AP = Λ.
>
> A note is given that $P^{-1}$ does not need to be calculated.

---

I attempted to solve this problem, but I do think not that my attempts are correct:

> Starting out I used the vectors ***u***, ***v***,***w*** to form an invertible matrix (and checked for linear independence).
>
> That gave the matrix **P:**
>
> $ \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3\\\
> 0&-1&1\\\
> 3&1&2\\\
> \end{pmatrix} $
>
> Using the info from M**u** = -5**u**, M**v** = 0**v**, M**w** = 3**w**
>
> =$\lambda  = -5, 0, 3$ to make a real diagonal matrix **M:**
>
> $ \begin{pmatrix}
> -5&0&0\\\
> 0&0&0\\\
> 0&0&3\\\
> \end{pmatrix} $
>
> $\Rightarrow P^{-1}MP = \Lambda $
>
> $ \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3\\\
> 0&-1&1\\\
> 3&1&2\\\
> \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
> -5&0&0\\\
> 0&0&0\\\
> 0&0&3\\\
> \end{pmatrix} \cdot \ \begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3\\\
> 0&-1&1\\\
> 3&1&2\\\
> \end{pmatrix} =  $  $\Lambda $

Comment: If you understand the one then you should understand the other: for any solution of $\;PAP^{-1}=\Lambda\;$ that you say you know, put $\;Q:=P^{-1}\;$ and thus get $\;Q^{-1}AQ=\Lambda\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$P^{−1}AP= Λ$$ your matrix $P$ is the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$ and Λ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Note that we need linearly independent eigenvectors in order for the matrix $P$ to be invertible.